# Why is my D code to sum a vector up x4 slower than C?

Tags: d

I was wondering why D code is so slow? I originally used std.algorithm.sum but the performance was even worse.

My D code:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    immutable int n = 10000000;
    int[] v = new int[n];
    fill(v,1);
    int total = 0;

    foreach (int i; 0 .. n) {
        total += v[i];
    }

    writeln(total);
}
```

Built using:

```
dmd -O arraysum.d
```

Equivalent C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10000000;
    int *v = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            v[i] = 1;
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            total += v[i];
    }

    printf("%d\n", total);
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
clang -O3 -o csum arraysum.c
```

Comment: and did you try `foreach (int el; v) {total += el;}`, also did you look at the compiled output? it's entirely possible that C++ optimized the loops out into just `total = 10000000;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can improve speed with `uninitializedArray` from `std.array` and use foreach over array directly:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.array;

void main()
{
    immutable int n = 10000000;
    auto v = uninitializedArray!(int[])(n);
    fill(v, 1);
    int total = 0;

    foreach (i; v) {
            total += i;
    }

    writeln(total);
}
```

and you should use `-release -inline -noboundscheck` parameters

For me with dmd is it 2x slower but with ldmd2(ldc) or gdc is same speed as C version

Comment: Wow, that worked and got identical speeds to my C example! I look forward to investigating more of D. I take my code was slow because it was implicitly initializing it with '0's.

Comment: @jimjampez and probably the excessive bounds-check in the loop

Answer (score 2):

Try building it with gcc or ldc. 
The dmd compiler is the language reference other compilers should use, it doesn't produce particularly fast binaries though. 
gcc is much better.